# 2 web application in one solution asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

it is possible to create two different asp.net website in one solution or in other way and use the same resource such as the database, CSS files, and images.

I have to make a project that has a different type of users, the guest, normal users, special users and admin.

the direct URL of the website make for guest and normal register users. and for admin and special user, they have to open other forms that have different styles but both the website using the same resource as I mentioned above.

so it's possible to do that, and how I can make it in asp.net

regards,

Comment: Solutions are just "packages of projects", so yes you can. You could technically create every project in it's own solution, build it separately and set the references to the .dll, or other build artifacts and it would work. Would be hell to debug though. I hesitated posting that as an answer since it's basically "Yes".

Comment: You can organize application using Area for  example, admin and special user you can partition Web applications into smaller units

Comment: If you are about to create website in `mvc`, then i would suggest you to go for [Areas](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/mvc-areas-with-example)